# Which is the easier CMS to integrate with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, content-management-system

I was trying develop a website with Cakephp and Joomla... But lately I've been founding a lot of barriers that create difficulties implementing things that would have been a lot easier if I only developped using one of the components.

So, in your point of view (as someone with more experience than me), is it worth to integrate CakePhp with a CMS?

If yes, what do you think its the best and easier CMS to integrate with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my point of view i wouldn't try. I think there would be a lot of crossover functionality and a lot of conflict. Either use Cake and write a CMS and the other elements you want or pick a CMS and develop the other elements you want as add-ins/plugins.

Joomla, Drupal, Xaraya, Expression-engine etc are all extensible so pick the one that is the best fit and has the ability to be extended or maybe already has plugins you require.

Another option would be to use Joomla as the CMS and Cake for the  other element you want, keep them as separate entities but skin then identically and make the navigation seamless. In this case about the only thing you would need to integrate would be state.

Comment: I agree with PurplePilot, don't bother trying to integrate a non CakePHP CMS with a CakePHP site - you'll be in for a world of pain. Either use one of the existing ones out there, e.g. Wildflower as suggested by Wil, or Croogo [http://croogo.org], or alternatively, using CakePHP's code generation tool, bake, you can knock up a CMS in no time at all.

Comment: The last option you mention is essentially integrating 2 separate applications, which is perfectly fine. But my preferred approach is to build a general-purpose CMS using Cake, and then integrate more specialized applications into it (a forum, a shopping cart, etc.) as necessary. 

If you're using a general-purpose CMS or CMS-framework, then I see little point in integrating a Cake app into it. A plugin for the CMS-framework would seem more logical for minor functionality/customization, specialized prepackaged apps for larger features.

Answer (score 10):

Or use Croogo (http://croogo.org/)

A CakePHP CMS.  I like Croogo's implementation more than Wildflower and the admin UI looks a bit similar to Wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

There are some out there already that are on Cake from the ground up.  Wildflower for example

http://wf.klevo.sk/

Answer (score 4):

I have a cakephp site that is running wordpress in it's public_html/blog folder and it is doing great.

They are basically two separate sites, with two separate backend but it is fairly easy to create a model for the wordpress database if you want to pull in any data (eg. posts, pages, comments) and use it in the cakephp site.

As far a integrating the two I don't think it is a good idea if it needs to be a seamless experience for the backend users, most frontend users won't notice the difference because you can use the same style sheet and images.

If you want any more about my experiences with the combination let me know!

Answer (score 4):

Cakeui is a rip of Croogo. Infinitas CMS could be what you're looking for if you want a full blown application or check this site for a list of good [CakePHP Cms](http://cakephpcms.com/)

Answer (score 3):

As the developer of Croogo, I will be biased and recommend you to check it out at http://croogo.org. It comes with a web based installer too and you should be up and running in minutes.

Another CakePHP based CMS is Infinitas which has more features (including shopping cart). Both are based on the latest version of the framework (1.3 at the moment) and are actively developed.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a lot of CMS type apps with Cake and was thinking along the same lines. I've tried Joomla, Drupal and Wordpress but still had a dirty feeling in my mouth that I was failing by using Cake just for the sake of it or vice versa.

The most important common denominator, in my experience, is the back-end. It is re-used most often, but gets the least input.

Now I have built my own CMS with CakePHP. The intention is to 'opensource' it, but it's not quite ready yet.

I don't think it is worth the headache trying to combine, then maintain Cake and a 3rd party CMS. Save your best modules and components and build your own. The blog tutorial will give you a good head start and you can cherrypick what you like from other sources, rewriting it to suit your ideals. The benefit is you will then know the CMS inside out and have it working just the way you want. You'll learn a lot along the way as well.